# Explicit form of recursive function

Tags: functions, summation, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Given recursive function:

$$T(x)=2T(\frac{x}{2})+\frac{2}{\log (x)}$$

**reach an explicit form:**

We already solved it in class. However I can't seem to remember, how was it...

I Wrote it in these stages, but now I am stumped and can't figure it out:

$2(2T(\frac{x}{4})+\frac{2}{\log \frac{x}{2}})+\frac{2}{\log x}$

$2^2T(\frac{x}{2^2})+\frac{2^2}{\log \frac{x}{2^1}}+\frac{2}{\log \frac{x}{2^0}}$

$...=2^kT\frac{x}{2^k}+\sum ...$

I recognized some pattern, but wasn't able to express it using Sigma...

is this progression look valid? like I said the teacher solved it in class, however I am not able to restore it...

Comment: Are you suggesting $T(x) = 3x$? This seems not to fulfill the equation.

Comment: In summation notation this is $$2^kT\left(\frac x{2^k}\right)+2\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{2^i}{\log x-i\log2}$$

Comment: @mvw the main goal is to to proof or to disprove the function

Comment: This is not an solution, unless you apply some other concept of equality.

Comment: @mvw perhaps the solution I have written is wrong? Without looking at the solution it it possible to reach an explicit form?

Comment: Looks like a job for the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Introduction)

Comment: @mvw yes, originally this was given in a computer science course. sorry if not suitable for this forum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(x)=2T(\frac{x}{2})+\frac{2}{\log (x)}$$
$$T(2x)=2T(x)+\frac{2}{\log (2x)}$$
$T(x)=\frac12T(2x)-\frac{1}{\log (2x)}$

$\frac12T(2x)=\frac{1}{2^2}T(2^2x)-\frac{1}{2\log (2^2x)}$

$\frac{1}{2^2}T(2^2x)=\frac{1}{2^3}T(2^3x)-\frac{1}{2^2\log (2^3x)}$

Etc.

$\frac{1}{2^n}T(2^n x)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}T(2^{n+1}x)-\frac{1}{2^n\log(2^{n+1}x)}$

Adding the above equations leads to :

$$T(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}T(2^{n+1}x)-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k\log(2^{k+1}x)}$$

$$T(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}T(2^{n+1}x)-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k\log(x)+2^k(k+1)\log(2)}$$
For $n\to\infty$ we suppose that $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}T(2^{n+1}x)\to 0$. This will be checked latter.
$$T(x)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k\log(x)+2^k(k+1)\log(2)}$$
$$T(x)=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac12\right)^k}{\left(\frac{\log(2x)}{\ln(2)}+k\right)}$$

Lerch function $\Phi(z,s,a)$ , with $z=\frac12\quad;\quad s=1 \quad;\quad a=\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(2)}\quad$ , Eq.$(1)$ in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html
$$T(x)=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\:\Phi\left(\frac12 \:,\: 1 \:,\: \frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(2)}\right)$$

IN ADDITION :

Limit of $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}T(2^{n+1}x)$ for $n\to\infty$ :

$T(2^n x)=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\:\Phi\left(\frac12 \:,\: 1 \:,\: a)\right)$  with $a=\frac{\ln(2^{n+1}x)}{\ln(2)}=n+1+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$

For $n\to\infty\quad;\quad a\sim n\to\infty\quad;\quad \Phi\left(\frac12 \:,\: 1 \:,\: a)\right)\sim \frac{2}{a}\sim \frac{2}{n}\to 0 \quad ;$

Thus $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}T(2^{n+1}x)\sim -\frac{2}{\ln(2)2^{n+1}n}\to 0$ as it was supposed.

DIRECT PROVE :

From the definition of the Lerch function $\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k+a)^s}$

$$T(x)=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\:\Phi\left(\frac12 \:,\: 1 \:,\: \frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(2)}\right)=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac12)^k}{(k+\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(2)})}$$

$$T(x)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k(k\ln(2)+\ln(2x))}$$
$$T(x/2)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k(k\ln(2)+\ln(x))}$$
$$2T(x/2)+\frac{2}{\ln(x)}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}(k\ln(2)+\ln(x))}+\frac{2}{\ln(x)}$$

$$2T(x/2)+\frac{2}{\ln(x)}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}(k\ln(2)+\ln(x))}$$
$$2T(x/2)+\frac{2}{\ln(x)}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}((k-1)\ln(2)+\ln(2x))}$$
Changing the index $(k-1)$ to $k$ :
$$2T(x/2)+\frac{2}{\ln(x)}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k}(k\ln(2)+\ln(2x))}=T(x)$$

Comment: I  am really sorry for the delay. I didn't mention that  the function stops at the term T(1)=1.Can The solution youve written be modified according to this term, because i am new to the subject and its a bit difficult for me to comprehend it, especially the lerch function which we havent study in class...?